# Spacing Issues on iOS with Horizontal Scrolling Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with my horizontal scrolling menu on iOS. On iOS, the text overlaps:

[image]

But appears fine in various devices when I check using Chrome's dev tools:

[image]

Here's the CSS:

```
#sub-menu ul {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    max-width: 1168px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Try it out here: http://jsbin.com/gocuwayoca/5/

I'm struggling to find out what I'm doing wrong.